# How to set destination website on MSDeploy.exe command line

Tags: msdeploy, webdeploy

I have a Web Deploy 3.5 package that I want to deploy to a remote server. How do I specify the name of the site on the MSDeploy.exe command line?

Here's what I have so far:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe
    -source:package='package.zip' 
    -dest:auto,computerName="ServerName",includeAcls="False" 
    -verb:sync 
    -disableLink:AppPoolExtension 
    -disableLink:ContentExtension 
    -disableLink:CertificateExtension 
    -setParamFile:"package.SetParameters.xml"
```

But the name of the site is specified in the `package.SetParamters.xml` file, and I'd prefer to set it on the command line. Some of the places I want to deploy this package are different sites located on the same server, like our Stage and UAT sites.

I've looked at using the iisApp and appHostConfig providers described here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569040%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

But I'm having trouble using those in combination with a package file.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can override it using `setParam`:

```
msdeploy.exe
    -source:package='package.zip' 
    -dest:auto,computerName="ServerName",includeAcls="False" 
    -verb:sync 
    -disableLink:AppPoolExtension 
    -disableLink:ContentExtension 
    -disableLink:CertificateExtension 
    -setParamFile:"package.SetParameters.xml"
    -setParam:name="IIS Web Application Name",value="site name"
```

Comment: I'm having a difficult time getting msdeploy to accept the "IIS Web Application Name" string. It's not parsing the quote marks properly.

Comment: @dthrasher - Powershell?

Comment: Actually, I was using the command line runner in TeamCity, my continuous integration server. So I'm not currently doing this in the PowerShell environment. But it keeps trying to split the parameters on the spaces between "IIS Web Application Name".

Comment: I had the same issue with the split params Scott's answer seems to handle this.

Comment: I've found that setParam doesn't allow me to override custom required parameters if I also use setParamFile.  I have a working msdeploy.exe command-line using just setParam, but as soon as I append setParamFile to it, it complains about various required custom parameters that "argument cannot be null or empty."  If I remove the setParam items and instead put them in the SetParameters.xml, then it works again.  But it seems you can't have both, at least not with required custom parameters.

Comment: I have tried out all of the answers from here and from a bunch of other pages. None of them was working for me... But now I have a simpler solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21056251/how-to-set-destination-website-on-msdeploy-exe-command-line/50448428#50448428

Answer (score 15):

To do the same in Powershell (see [Richard Szalay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21070382/81595)), you have to be a little careful about the command line argument handling - especially where spaces are involved. I find that it is best to pass them as an array where the desired command line arguments are effectively split on the space character. Note that the lines below are comma separated and also that the parameter name 'IIS Web Application' is split. I left that one on one line for improved readability.

```
$msdeploy = "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe";

$msdeployArguments = 
    '-source:package="package.zip"',
    '-dest:auto,computerName="<ServerName>",includeAcls="False"',
    '-verb:sync',
    '-disableLink:AppPoolExtension',
    '-disableLink:ContentExtension',
    '-disableLink:CertificateExtension',
    '-setParam:name="IIS', 'Web', 'Application', 'Name",value="<WebsiteName>"'

& $msdeploy $msdeployArguments
```

**Update**

I had problems when I went back to parametrize the website Name. Because I had used single quotes for the strings, I chose to use concatenation rather than [string interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation). Unfortunately, the commas that delimited the elements in the array seem to have been evaluated prior to the concatenation. The result was that instead of concatenating strings within an array element, I was concatenating new elements to the array. My solution was to use parentheses to surround the array element and force the concatenation to be performed first.

```
$msdeployArguments = 
    '-source:package="package.zip"',
    ('-dest:auto,computerName="' + $webServerName + '",includeAcls="True"'),
    '-verb:sync',
    '-disableLink:AppPoolExtension',
    '-disableLink:ContentExtension',
    '-disableLink:CertificateExtension',
    '-setParam:name="IIS', 'Web', 'Application', ('Name",value="' + $websiteName + '"');
```

Comment: Wow. That's crazy. Thanks for the tip! I'd never have thought of using an arguments array to fix the whitespace issue.

Comment: I was able to set the parameter with: `-setParam:kind=ProviderPath,scope=iisApp,value=YourSiteName`

Comment: i specified like this: `$siteNameParam='name="IIS Web Application Name",value="Default Web Site/TestService"'` and use it:`msdeploy -verb:sync -source:package="pack/infoservice.wcf.zip" -dest:auto,computerName=iis-dtp -setParam:$siteNameParam`

Answer (score 4):

I have tried out all of the answers from here (and basically all answers from the internet) none of them was working for me. Not sure why. 
Then I found [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericparvin/2014/09/12/backup-strategies-with-web-deploy/) page which explains how to use MSDeploy for BackUps (I just reversed it to use for deploy). The secret souse is "**contentPath**". Which is a bit misleading because in this case not a path on the Disk (however I have seen examples which was using it to pass in the hosted Site Physical path). But I didn't wanted to use the Physical path. And you don't have to! The trick is: **it can contain the WebSite or child site (in IIS yoursite.com/shop, so I guess it is a path in IIS) name.**

**Usage for backup:**

```
msdeploy –verb:sync -source:contentPath="yoursite.com" -dest:package=c:\Backups\yoursite.zip
```

**Usage to deploy:**

```
msdeploy –verb:sync -source:package=c:\Deployment\yoursite.zip -dest:contentPath="yoursite.com"
```

I was wasting almost a day with declareParam, setParam, etc... However it is so simple!

Hope it helps...

Comment: Helped me as well. Neither 'site' query string in Web Deploy Service url nor -setParam name worked for me. Thank you, Sir!