# WebDeploy command line not working

Tags: powershell, webdeploy

I have a script that I had previously used to deploy using MS WebDeploy and it worked great.  I have just tried to use it again after a few months and now I get an error.

Here is the command line:

```
OA.Web.deploy.cmd /Y "/M:https://XXX.XX.XXX.XXX:8172/msdeploy.axd" /U:USERNAME /P:PASSWORD /A:Basic -allowUntrusted "-setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='demo'";
```

Here is the error that I am getting:

> Error: Unrecognized argument '"-setParam:name='IIS Web Application
>   Name',value='demo'"'. All arguments must begin with "-". Error
>   count: 1.

I have tried changing the command line to match this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21056251/how-to-set-destination-website-on-msdeploy-exe-command-line) and I get this error message instead:

```
Error: Unrecognized argument '"'IIS Web Application Name'"'. All arguments must
begin with "-".
Error count: 1.
```

I have tried running the command from both the regular command prompt as well as through powershell.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try to change the position of double quote: `-setParam:name="'IIS Web Application Name',value='demo'";`

Comment: Same error as the second error above.

Comment: try it in console cmd and not powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never gotten the -setParam to work properly for "IIS Web Application Name" except by using the PowerShell array trick described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25805588/19112) or by using a separate SetParameters.xml file.

I've seen plenty of posts on the Internet that indicate that the setParam syntax should work for a name with spaces -- and apparently it was working for you at some point, @drneel -- but I think we just have to chalk it up to a very, very brittle deployment tool.

Eventually, I gave up on generating the separate package altogether and just built and published directly from Visual Studio in my continuous integration server.

Comment: Accepted for the link to the other answer.  I as well gave up on deploying from the package and started deploying from visual studio.